# How do I rotate an icon with CSS upon decolapsing a list

Tags: css

I can't get an arrow-down character (icon) to rotate upwards upon uncollapsing and rotating downwards upon collapsing an list of items.

This is what I have so far, but obviously does not work...

```
.c-accordion li.open .material-icons {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

I thought the open-attribute would solve this, but alas.
A search on the internt did not provide the answer.
Any ideas?
All help is welcome.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("js-collapse");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.c-accordion li.open .material-icons {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.c-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  border-left: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  border-right: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
}
.c-accordion {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
ul.c-accordion.active, ul.c-accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.c-submenu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.c-submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.c-submenu li:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
.c-panel {
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class='c-menu'>
  <ul class="c-accordion">Section 1</ul>
  <ul class="c-accordion js-collapse">Section 2<i class="material-icons float-right">keyboard_arrow_down</i></ul>
    <ul class="c-submenu c-panel">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  <ul class="c-accordion">Section 3</ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the transition both ways. Try the following selectors:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("js-collapse");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.c-accordion li.open .material-icons {

}

ul.c-accordion .material-icons {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

ul.c-accordion.active .material-icons {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.c-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  border-left: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  border-right: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
}
.c-accordion {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
ul.c-accordion.active, ul.c-accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.c-submenu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.c-submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.c-submenu li:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
.c-panel {
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class='c-menu'>
  <ul class="c-accordion">Section 1</ul>
  <ul class="c-accordion js-collapse">Section 2<i class="material-icons float-right">keyboard_arrow_down</i></ul>
    <ul class="c-submenu c-panel">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  <ul class="c-accordion">Section 3</ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change this line `.c-accordion li.open .material-icons` by it `.c-accordion.js-collapse.active .material-icons.float-right`
and here is the result below

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("js-collapse");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.c-accordion.js-collapse.active .material-icons.float-right{
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
transition: all .3s ease;
}

.c-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  border-left: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  border-right: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
}
.c-accordion {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
ul.c-accordion.active, ul.c-accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.c-submenu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.c-submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.c-submenu li:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
.c-panel {
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
<ul class='c-menu'>
  <ul class="c-accordion">Section 1</ul>
  <ul class="c-accordion js-collapse">Section 2<i class="material-icons 
float-right">keyboard_arrow_down</i></ul>
    <ul class="c-submenu c-panel">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  <ul class="c-accordion">Section 3</ul>
</ul>
```